# ActiveMQ memory limit exceeded

Tags: activemq-classic

I try to configure ActiveMQ for the following behavior: when broker exceeds its memory limit, it should store message in persistence storage. If use the following configuration:

```
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setBrokerName("activemq");
    KahaDBPersistenceAdapter persistence = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
    persistence.setDirectory(new File(config.getProperty("amq.persistenceDir", "amq")));
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistence);
    broker.setVmConnectorURI(new URI("vm://activemq"));
    broker.getSystemUsage().getMemoryUsage().setLimit(64 * 1024 * 1024L);
    broker.getSystemUsage().getStoreUsage().setLimit(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 100L);
    broker.getSystemUsage().getTempUsage().setLimit(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 100L);
    PolicyEntry policyEntry = new PolicyEntry();
    policyEntry.setCursorMemoryHighWaterMark(50);
    policyEntry.setExpireMessagesPeriod(0L);
    policyEntry.setPendingDurableSubscriberPolicy(new StorePendingDurableSubscriberMessageStoragePolicy());
    policyEntry.setMemoryLimit(64 * 1024 * 1024L);
    policyEntry.setProducerFlowControl(false);
    broker.setDestinationPolicy(new PolicyMap());
    broker.getDestinationPolicy().setDefaultEntry(policyEntry);
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    broker.start();
```

However, this does not work. ActiveMQ still consumes as much memory as needed to store the full queue. I also tried to remove PolicyEntry, that caused broker to stop producers after memory limit is reached. I could find nothing in documentation about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I put in queue about 10Gb of messages and found that queue, though exceeding specified memory limit about 7 times, retains this factor constant, i.e. does not throw OutOfMemoryException. Limiting JVM with -Xmx flag to 512 mb causes OOME. I think, there is something wrong, but at least I can be sure, that if I give 1Gb to queue, JVM won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

we use a [storeCursor](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html) and set the memory limit as follows...this will limit the amount of memory for all queues to 100MB...

```
   <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="100mb">
                    <pendingQueuePolicy>
                        <storeCursor/>
                    </pendingQueuePolicy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

make sure you set the "destinations" that your policy should apply against...in my XML examples this is done using `queue=">"`, but your example is using a `new PolicyMap()`...try calling `policyEntry.setQueue(">")` instead to apply to all queues or add specific destinations to your PolicyMap,  etc.

see this test for a full example...

https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/PerDestinationStoreLimitTest.java

Comment: I *do* use store cursor. And I don't configure ActiveMQ through XML.

Comment: I tried both this:

        policyEntry.setPendingQueuePolicy(new StorePendingQueueMessageStoragePolicy());
        policyEntry.setPendingDurableSubscriberPolicy(new StorePendingDurableSubscriberMessageStoragePolicy());

and configuring through XML. Nothing helps though.

Comment: wasn't clear which cursor you were using...but we had the same issue using the VM cursor and this resolved it...regardless of whether you use XML/Java to configure it, the underlying issues sounds like the same...my example shows how we addressed it...perhaps its different though